How do I place these brick meshes onto this wall, so that they're all lined up correctly instead of scrambled together?
I'm trying to create a chimney, so I went with using geometry nodes to add a brick object onto a large cube. I want to hold onto the existing cube so that I could still make a textured wall, but I just want to add bricks on top of it to add some layers to the whole thing, more detail. The bricks are currently all randomly placed, some overlapping each other, the whole thing's a mess. How do I make them stick to the surface and not overlap?


Doesn't a "brick texture" work? It can be used both in shading and in geometry nodes

There is only one brick to duplicate to cover the large cube ? Or do you expect some randomness ?
